# DB2 Query running slow

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I am trying to speed up the below query which is running very slow. This is just half of the original query I am using and the other half is a union to another query.
Can someone please let me know if they are seeing any obvious red flags in the below query?

The other painful thing is, I am unbale to find any indexes in index adivsor.

```
WITH
PREORDER AS (
  SELECT
    *
  FROM ORDERPAR
),
TCALLORDER AS (
  SELECT
    TPODR#,TPAREA,TPSEQ#
  FROM "ORDER"
    INNER JOIN OPTPLANP ON ORODR# = TPODR# EXCEPTION
    JOIN OPPLAN ON OPORD# = TPODR#
    AND TPSEQ# = OPTCSQ
),
FIRSTEQUIPRRN AS (
  SELECT
    OEORD# EQUIPORDER,MIN(RRN(A)) FIRSTROW
  FROM OPEQUIP A
  GROUP BY OEORD#
  ORDER BY 1),
FIRSTEQUIPROW AS (
  SELECT
    OEORD#,OETRLR EQUIPMENTNUMBER
  FROM FIRSTEQUIPRRN
    INNER JOIN OPEQUIP B ON EQUIPORDER = OEORD#
    AND FIRSTROW = RRN(B)
),
STOPGROUP AS(
  SELECT
    SOORD STOPORDER,
    COUNT(*) STOPSREMAIN,
    MIN(SOSTP#) NEXTSTOP,
    MAX(SOAPPR) APPTREQ,
    MAX(SOAPTM) APPTMADE
  FROM STOPOFF
    INNER JOIN "ORDER" ON ORODR# = SOORD
  WHERE SOARDT = 0
  GROUP BY SOORD
  ORDER BY 1
),
ORDERMILES AS (
SELECT
  MMORD#,MMTOTAL
FROM MMILES
WHERE MMORD# IN ( SELECT ORODR# FROM "ORDER" )
  AND MMRECTYPE = 'O'
  AND MMDSP# = '00'
),
NEGCOUNT AS (
  SELECT
    COUNT(*) NEGOTIATIONS,BNORD#
  FROM LMNEG
  GROUP BY BNORD#
)
SELECT
  A.ORODR# ORDER_NUMBER,
  ORCUST SHIPPER_ID,
  CUSTMS.CUNAME SHIPPER_NAME,
  CUSTMS.CUBAD1 SHIPPER_ADDRESS_1,
  CUSTMS.CUBAD2 SHIPPER_ADDRESS_2,
  CUSTMS.CUBCTY SHIPPER_CITY,
  CUSTMS.CUBST SHIPPER_ST,
  CUSTMS.CUBZIP SHIPPER_ZIP,
  CUSTMS.CUBZP2 SHIPPER_ZIP_EXT,
  ORLDAT LOAD_AT_ID,
  CUSTML.CUNAME LOAD_AT_NAME,
  CUSTML.CUBAD1 LOAD_AT_ADDRESS_1,
  CUSTML.CUBAD2 LOAD_AT_ADDRESS_2,
  CUSTML.CUBCTY LOAD_AT_CITY,
  CUSTML.CUBST LOAD_AT_ST,
  CUSTML.CUBZIP LOAD_AT_ZIP,
  CUSTML.CUBZP2 LOAD_AT_ZIP_EXT,
  MCCL.C#DECLATD LOAD_AT_LATITUDE,
  MCCL.C#DECLOND LOAD_AT_LONGITUDE,
  CASE WHEN ORPDAT <> 0
    AND ORPTIM = '' THEN CVTDATETIM(CHAR(ORPDAT),'0000',CMCPUZ) WHEN ORPDAT <> 0 THEN CVTDATETIM(CHAR(ORPDAT),ORPTIM,CMCPUZ) WHEN ORPDAT = 0 THEN '0000-00-00T00:00:00-00:00' END AS EARLY_PU_DATE_TIME,
  CASE WHEN ORAPDT <> 0
    AND ORAPTM = '' THEN CVTDATETIM(CHAR(ORAPDT),'0000',CMCPUZ) WHEN ORAPDT <> 0 THEN CVTDATETIM(CHAR(ORAPDT),ORAPTM,CMCPUZ) WHEN ORAPDT = 0 THEN '0000-00-00T00:00:00-00:00' END AS LATE_PU_DATE_TIME,
  CASE WHEN ORDDAT <> 0
    AND ORDTIM = '' THEN CVTDATETIM(CHAR(ORDDAT),'0000',CMCPUZ) WHEN ORDDAT <> 0 THEN CVTDATETIM(CHAR(ORDDAT),ORDTIM,CMCPUZ) WHEN ORDDAT = 0 THEN '0000-00-00T00:00:00-00:00' END AS EARLY_DELV_DATE_TIME,
  ORESTR EST_REVENUE,
  A.ORDV# ORDER_DIV,
  ORCONS CONSIGNEE_ID,
  CUSTMC.CUNAME CONSIGNEE_NAME,
  CUSTMC.CUBAD1 CONSIGNEE_ADDRESS_1,
  CUSTMC.CUBAD2 CONSIGNEE_ADDRESS_2,
  CUSTMC.CUBCTY CONSIGNEE_CITY,
  CUSTMC.CUBST CONSIGNEE_ST,
  CUSTMC.CUBZIP CONSIGNEE_ZIP,
  CUSTMC.CUBZP2 CONSIGNEE_ZIP_EXT,
  MCCC.C#DECLATD CONSIGNEE_LATITUDE,
  MCCC.C#DECLOND CONSIGNEE_LONGITUDE,
  OREQTY TRAILER_TYPE,
  ORSPEC ORDER_MESSAGE,
  A.ORSTP# ADDITIONAL_STOPS,
  ORCOMC CMDTY_CODE,
  ORCOMD CMDTY_DESCRIPTION,
  (COALESCE(MMTOTAL,0)) ORDER_MILES,
  ORWGT ORDER_WGT,
  OROCTY ORIGIN_CITY_CODE,
  CITYOR.CINAME ORIGIN_CITY,
  OROST ORIGIN_ST,
  ORDCTY DEST_CITY_CODE,
  CITYDEST.CINAME DEST_CITY_NAME,
  ORDST DEST_ST,
  ORARA PICK_UP_AREA,
  ORPDRV PLAN_INFO,
  ORLD# NUMBER_LDS,
  OR#DSP NUMBER_DISP,
  CASE WHEN ORSHDT <> 0
    AND ORSHTM = '' THEN CVTDATETIM(CHAR(ORSHDT),'0000',CMCPUZ) WHEN ORSHDT <> 0 THEN CVTDATETIM(CHAR(ORSHDT),ORSHTM,CMCPUZ) WHEN ORSHDT = 0 THEN '0000-00-00T00:00:00-00:00' END AS SHIP_DATE_TIME,
  ORNWPK NEW_PICKUP_AREA,
  (COALESCE(EQUIPMENTNUMBER,' ')) EQUIPMENT_NUMBER,
  (COALESCE(APPTREQ,'N')) APPT_REQ,
  (COALESCE(APPTMADE,'N')) APPT_MADE,
  (COALESCE(TPSEQ#,' ')) PRE_T_SEQ,
  (COALESCE(TPAREA,' ')) PRE_T_AREA,
  ORDSP# LOAD_DISPATCHED,
  CASE WHEN APPTREQ = ' '
  AND APPTMADE = ' ' THEN APPTMADE WHEN APPTREQ = 'N'
  AND APPTMADE = 'Y' THEN APPTMADE WHEN APPTREQ = 'Y'
  AND APPTMADE = 'Y' THEN 'Y' WHEN APPTREQ = 'N'
  AND APPTMADE = 'N' THEN APPTREQ WHEN APPTREQ = ' ' OR APPTMADE = ' ' THEN 'N' ELSE 'N' END AVAPPTREQ,
  ORSTAT,
  ORPDAT,
  CUSTMS.CUSVRP CUST_SERV_REP,
  NEGOTIATIONS
FROM SUBSIDIARY,"ORDER" A
  LEFT OUTER JOIN CUSTMAST CUSTMS ON ORCUST = CUSTMS.CUCODE
  LEFT OUTER JOIN CUSTMAST CUSTML ON ORLDAT = CUSTML.CUCODE
  LEFT OUTER JOIN CUSTMAST CUSTMC ON ORCONS = CUSTMC.CUCODE
  LEFT OUTER JOIN MCCSTLLP MCCS ON ORCUST = MCCS.C#CODE
  LEFT OUTER JOIN MCCSTLLP MCCL ON ORLDAT = MCCL.C#CODE
  LEFT OUTER JOIN MCCSTLLP MCCC ON ORCONS = MCCC.C#CODE
  LEFT OUTER JOIN CITIES CITYOR ON OROST = CITYOR.CIST AND OROCTY = CITYOR.CICTY
  LEFT OUTER JOIN CITIES CITYDEST ON ORDST = CITYDEST.CIST AND ORDCTY = CITYDEST.CICTY
  LEFT OUTER JOIN MMILES ON MMORD# = A.ORODR# AND MMRECTYPE = 'O' AND MMDSP# = '00'
  LEFT OUTER JOIN FIRSTEQUIPROW ON A.ORODR# = OEORD#
  LEFT OUTER JOIN STOPGROUP ON A.ORODR# = STOPORDER
  EXCEPTION JOIN OPPLAN ON OPORD# = A.ORODR#
  LEFT OUTER JOIN TCALLORDER ON TPODR# = A.ORODR#
  LEFT OUTER JOIN NEGCOUNT ON BNORD# = A.ORODR#
WHERE ( ORSTAT <> 'C' )
```

Comment: Have you studied the access-plan for the query, that is the usual fist step...

Comment: Its the IBMi. How can I study the access path?

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=tools-print-sql-information

Comment: Use the [Visual Explain (VE)](https://www.itechsol.com/using-visual-explain-in-access-client-solutions-to-enhance-the-performance-of-sql-processing/) functionality in the Run SQL Scripts component of IBM Access Client Solution (ACS)

Answer (score 0):

Using the [Visual Explain (VE)](https://www.itechsol.com/using-visual-explain-in-access-client-solutions-to-enhance-the-performance-of-sql-processing/) functionality in the Run SQL Scripts component of IBM Access Client Solution (ACS) will show you where the query is spending it's time and any advised indexes.

Having said that, the use of RRN() is generally a bad idea and the way you're using it here is very suspect.

Also the nice thing about the use of Common Table Expressions (`with MyCTE ...`) is that you can check the results partway through by adding a `select * from lastCte;`

So in your case,

```
 WITH PREORDER AS
 (
 SELECT *
 FROM
 ORDERPAR
 )
 , TCALLORDER AS
 (
 SELECT
 TPODR#
 , TPAREA
 , TPSEQ#
 FROM
 "ORDER"
 INNER JOIN
 OPTPLANP
 ON
 ORODR# = TPODR#
 EXCEPTION JOIN
 OPPLAN
 ON
 OPORD# = TPODR#
 AND TPSEQ# = OPTCSQ
 )
 select * from tcallorder;
```

As you continue down the CTEs, you can see how the VE plan changes.

Answer (score 0):

you have to structure the query to have a chance of understanding and troubleshooting it.

run the `strdbg` command. Then run the query from the `STRSQL` prompt. You should see "suggested access path" messages in the joblog.

And run the with queries in succession. The first with query on its own. Then with queries 1 thru 2.  Then 1 thru 3. Point being you are running them to see where the bottleneck is.

```
WITH PREORDER AS
 ( SELECT *  FROM ORDERPAR    ), 
TCALLORDER AS
( SELECT  TPODR#, TPAREA, TPSEQ#
  FROM    "ORDER"
  INNER JOIN  OPTPLANP
  ON      ORODR# = TPODR#
  EXCEPTION JOIN OPPLAN
  ON     OPORD# = TPODR# AND TPSEQ# = OPTCSQ
),
FIRSTEQUIPRRN AS
( SELECT OEORD# EQUIPORDER, MIN(RRN(A)) FIRSTROW
  FROM   OPEQUIP A
  GROUP BY OEORD#
  ORDER BY 1
),
FIRSTEQUIPROW AS
( SELECT OEORD#, OETRLR EQUIPMENTNUMBER
  FROM   FIRSTEQUIPRRN
  INNER JOIN OPEQUIP B
  ON    EQUIPORDER = OEORD# AND FIRSTROW = RRN(B)
),
STOPGROUP AS
( SELECT  SOORD STOPORDER, COUNT(*) STOPSREMAIN, MIN(SOSTP#) NEXTSTOP, MAX(SOAPPR) APPTREQ,
          MAX(SOAPTM) APPTMADE
  FROM    STOPOFF
  INNER JOIN "ORDER"
  ON      ORODR# = SOORD
  WHERE   SOARDT = 0
  GROUP BY SOORD
  ORDER BY 1
),
ORDERMILES AS
( SELECT  MMORD#, MMTOTAL
  FROM    MMILES
  WHERE   MMORD# IN ( SELECT ORODR#
                      FROM   "ORDER" )
          AND MMRECTYPE = 'O' AND MMDSP# = '00'
),
NEGCOUNT AS
( SELECT  COUNT(*) NEGOTIATIONS, BNORD#
  FROM    LMNEG
  GROUP BY BNORD#
)

SELECT   A.ORODR# ORDER_NUMBER, ORCUST SHIPPER_ID, CUSTMS.CUNAME SHIPPER_NAME,
         CUSTMS.CUBAD1 SHIPPER_ADDRESS_1, CUSTMS.CUBAD2 SHIPPER_ADDRESS_2, CUSTMS.CUBCTY SHIPPER_CITY, 
         CUSTMS.CUBST SHIPPER_ST, CUSTMS.CUBZIP SHIPPER_ZIP, CUSTMS.CUBZP2 SHIPPER_ZIP_EXT,
         ORLDAT LOAD_AT_ID, CUSTML.CUNAME LOAD_AT_NAME, CUSTML.CUBAD1 LOAD_AT_ADDRESS_1, CUSTML.CUBAD2 LOAD_AT_ADDRESS_2,
         CUSTML.CUBCTY LOAD_AT_CITY, CUSTML.CUBST LOAD_AT_ST, CUSTML.CUBZIP LOAD_AT_ZIP,
         CUSTML.CUBZP2 LOAD_AT_ZIP_EXT, MCCL.C#DECLATD LOAD_AT_LATITUDE, MCCL.C#DECLOND LOAD_AT_LONGITUDE,
         CASE WHEN ORPDAT <> 0 AND ORPTIM = ''
              THEN CVTDATETIM(CHAR(ORPDAT),'0000', CMCPUZ)
              WHEN ORPDAT <> 0
              THEN CVTDATETIM(CHAR(ORPDAT),ORPTIM, CMCPUZ)
              WHEN ORPDAT = 0
              THEN '0000-00-00T00:00:00-00:00' END AS EARLY_PU_DATE_TIME,
         CASE WHEN ORAPDT <> 0 AND ORAPTM = ''
              THEN CVTDATETIM(CHAR(ORAPDT),'0000', CMCPUZ)
              WHEN ORAPDT <> 0
              THEN CVTDATETIM(CHAR(ORAPDT),ORAPTM, CMCPUZ)
              WHEN ORAPDT = 0
              THEN '0000-00-00T00:00:00-00:00' END AS LATE_PU_DATE_TIME,
         CASE WHEN ORDDAT <> 0 AND ORDTIM = ''
              THEN CVTDATETIM(CHAR(ORDDAT),'0000',CMCPUZ)
              WHEN ORDDAT <> 0
              THEN CVTDATETIM(CHAR(ORDDAT),ORDTIM, CMCPUZ)
              WHEN ORDDAT = 0
              THEN '0000-00-00T00:00:00-00:00' END AS EARLY_DELV_DATE_TIME,
          ORESTR EST_REVENUE, A.ORDV# ORDER_DIV, ORCONS CONSIGNEE_ID, CUSTMC.CUNAME CONSIGNEE_NAME,
          CUSTMC.CUBAD1 CONSIGNEE_ADDRESS_1, CUSTMC.CUBAD2 CONSIGNEE_ADDRESS_2, CUSTMC.CUBCTY CONSIGNEE_CITY,
          CUSTMC.CUBST CONSIGNEE_ST, CUSTMC.CUBZIP CONSIGNEE_ZIP, CUSTMC.CUBZP2 CONSIGNEE_ZIP_EXT,
          MCCC.C#DECLATD CONSIGNEE_LATITUDE, MCCC.C#DECLOND CONSIGNEE_LONGITUDE, OREQTY TRAILER_TYPE,
          ORSPEC ORDER_MESSAGE, A.ORSTP# ADDITIONAL_STOPS, ORCOMC CMDTY_CODE, ORCOMD CMDTY_DESCRIPTION,
          (COALESCE(MMTOTAL, 0)) ORDER_MILES, ORWGT ORDER_WGT, OROCTY ORIGIN_CITY_CODE,
          CITYOR.CINAME ORIGIN_CITY, OROST ORIGIN_ST, ORDCTY DEST_CITY_CODE, CITYDEST.CINAME DEST_CITY_NAME,
          ORDST DEST_ST, ORARA PICK_UP_AREA, ORPDRV PLAN_INFO, ORLD# NUMBER_LDS, OR#DSP NUMBER_DISP,
          CASE WHEN ORSHDT <> 0 AND ORSHTM = ''
               THEN CVTDATETIM(CHAR(ORSHDT),'0000',CMCPUZ)
          WHEN ORSHDT <> 0
          THEN CVTDATETIM(CHAR(ORSHDT),ORSHTM,CMCPUZ)
          WHEN ORSHDT = 0
          THEN '0000-00-00T00:00:00-00:00'
          END AS SHIP_DATE_TIME,
          ORNWPK NEW_PICKUP_AREA, (COALESCE(EQUIPMENTNUMBER, ' ')) EQUIPMENT_NUMBER,
          (COALESCE(APPTREQ, 'N')) APPT_REQ, (COALESCE(APPTMADE, 'N')) APPT_MADE,
          (COALESCE(TPSEQ#, ' ')) PRE_T_SEQ, (COALESCE(TPAREA, ' ')) PRE_T_AREA, ORDSP# LOAD_DISPATCHED,
          CASE WHEN APPTREQ = ' ' AND APPTMADE = ' '
               THEN APPTMADE
               WHEN APPTREQ = 'N' AND APPTMADE = 'Y'
               THEN APPTMADE
               WHEN APPTREQ = 'Y' AND APPTMADE = 'Y'
               THEN 'Y'
               WHEN APPTREQ = 'N' AND APPTMADE = 'N'
               THEN APPTREQ
               WHEN APPTREQ = ' '  OR APPTMADE = ' '
               THEN 'N'
               ELSE 'N' END AVAPPTREQ,
         ORSTAT, ORPDAT, CUSTMS.CUSVRP CUST_SERV_REP, NEGOTIATIONS
FROM     SUBSIDIARY, "ORDER" A
LEFT OUTER JOIN  CUSTMAST CUSTMS
ON       ORCUST = CUSTMS.CUCODE
LEFT OUTER JOIN CUSTMAST CUSTML
ON       ORLDAT = CUSTML.CUCODE
LEFT OUTER JOIN CUSTMAST CUSTMC
ON       ORCONS = CUSTMC.CUCODE
LEFT OUTER JOIN MCCSTLLP MCCS
ON       ORCUST = MCCS.C#CODE
LEFT OUTER JOIN MCCSTLLP MCCL
ON       ORLDAT = MCCL.C#CODE
LEFT OUTER JOIN MCCSTLLP MCCC
ON       ORCONS = MCCC.C#CODE
LEFT OUTER JOIN CITIES CITYOR
ON       OROST = CITYOR.CIST AND OROCTY = CITYOR.CICTY
LEFT OUTER JOIN CITIES CITYDEST
ON       ORDST = CITYDEST.CIST AND ORDCTY = CITYDEST.CICTY
LEFT OUTER JOIN MMILES
ON       MMORD# = A.ORODR# AND MMRECTYPE = 'O' AND MMDSP# = '00'
LEFT OUTER JOIN FIRSTEQUIPROW
ON       A.ORODR# = OEORD#
LEFT OUTER JOIN STOPGROUP
ON       A.ORODR# = STOPORDER
EXCEPTION JOIN OPPLAN
ON       OPORD# = A.ORODR#
LEFT OUTER JOIN TCALLORDER
ON       TPODR# = A.ORODR#
LEFT OUTER JOIN NEGCOUNT
ON BNORD# = A.ORODR#
WHERE    ( ORSTAT <> 'C' )
```